# html5 Web SQL storage using different js files

Tags: javascript, sql, html, storage

I have a first.js which I open the database:

```
$(function(){ 
    initDatabase();
});

function initDatabase() {

    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Local Databases are not supported by your browser. Please use a Webkit browser for this demo');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'MyDB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'First DB';
            var maxSize = 100000; // in bytes
            DB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            //dropTables();
            createTables();

        }
    } catch(e) {
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version mismatch.
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error "+ e +".");
        }
        return;
    } 
}
```

Then, I want to execute sql statements from another file: second.js

```
function prueba_funcion () {
    DB.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM categorias;", [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
        }
    );
}
```

I receive this error: `DB is not defined`

In my HTML code I include first.js before second.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/second.js"></script>
```

But I cant get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by variable scope.  If you want the variable `DB` to be global in scope, you have to instantize it outside of a function.  Simply adding `var DB = null;` to `first.js` at the very top will probably solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I receive this error now: Cannot call method 'transaction' of null

Comment: Then it sounds like you have other issues with whatever the function `openDatabase` returns.  Looks like you're using Firebug... after you call `openDatabase`, console.log(DB) and go from there.  This must be part of some framework or library?  It is not part of vanilla javascript.

Comment: @Mateo, that is is because you are calling database before initializing it. `$(function(){ initDatabase(); });` will wait for page to load. You don't need to wait. Just put initDatabase() at the very end of the first.js